# what signals the client sending of next request in HTTP persistent connections

Tags: http, sockets, persistent-connection

In HTTP/1.1 (persistent connections), what is the "signal" which prompts the client to send the next HTTP request? Is there anything else besides Content-Length?

I'm trying to build a simple gateway, which would bridge the TCP traffic across files. I have two apps:

- "server" opens a socket and waits for connections. When the connection is established it forwards everything it gets ot the output file, at the same time forwarding everything from input file back to the socket
- "client" waits for content in the above output file and makes the connection to the server, sends data to it and writes the received data back to the above input file.

In other words: everything I get through socket is redirected through files to another socket, and vice versa.

AFAIK this should be completely transparent, but persistent connections do not work as expected.

I am testing with Firefox - what happens is that FF sends two GETs and receives two responses. But then it just sits there and waits as if it hasn't received all data yet... After 5 seconds (server responds with "Keep-Alive: timeout=5", so this fits) one of the sides closes the connection and reestablishes it and sending continues for a few files, when it gets stuck again.

I have listened with WireShark, but could not spot anything out of ordinary. Any idea what is going on?

**UPDATE**: below is a screenshot of WireShark log. It shows that the HTTP connection is sent much too late, after TCP connections closes (notice the times). Judging from my logs it was sent right away. Any idea why this discrepancy? Should I "flush" the socket somehow? I'm using Python.

[image: WireShark log]

Comment: Besides Content-Length there is Chunked-Encoding

Comment: Thanks! But since I am sending the HTTP traffic as it is (I don't change it) I guess this shouldn't matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either Content-Length or Chunked-Encoding (or if the connection is closed) which "signals" the client the length/end of data.

After the HTTP data has been received the browser keeps the tcp/ip connection open for some time to allow further requests to the same server over the same tcp/ip connection.

Comment: It turns out the problem was something entirely different. Firefox (and Epiphany) was waiting because it tried to establish a second connection, which of course was being put on hold. Setting max-connections-per-server to 1 solved the problem. Thank you both for your answers, they are both correct!

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'signal'. The client sends the next request when it is ready to do so.

> But then it just sits there and waits as if it hasn't received all
>   data yet

So it probably *hasn't* received all the data yet. Are you writing it out exactly when it comes in? and flushing any buffers?

Comment: I am sending everything right away (logs tell me so). Are there any buffers I should flush on client-side socket? I just do conn.sendall(data). It returns immediately, no error. Another thing: socket is set to nonblocking - but I guess this applies to recv() only, right?

Comment: @johndodo If the socket is non-blocking it doesn't have to write all the data you give it. Are you checking the result of your writes?

Comment: I am using sendall() so I should get an exception if write fails. AFAIK non-blocking applies to reads only?